# break long words only css Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a comment wrapper

Where there is two cases

**CASE ONE** Short words

```
   <div class="comment">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
   laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    </div>
```

**CASE TWO** Long words mixed with short  words.

```
   <div class="comment">
   LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelitseddoeiusmodtemporLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelitseddoeiusmodtemporLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelitseddoeiusmodtemporLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelitseddoeiusmodtemporLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelitseddoeiusmodtemporLoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelitseddoeiusmodtempor  
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
     laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
       </div>
```

I've been checking questions and I dont want to use `word-break: break-all;` because it breaks all words indistinctly.

I want to know if possible to dectec with Jquery the size of each words and if one word is longer than..`30` characters it break it else nothing.

Comment: you can limit the `width` of `<div class="comment">`

Comment: or put the text in a `<p>` and ilmit the width of that instead of the `<div>`

Comment: the with of the container is responsive `width:100%`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `overflow-wrap: break-word` ... as it will only create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without overflowing.

Also adding max-width to your container, as I would imagine you would not want line length's getting too long for readability on larger breakpoints.

Comment: If my answer did help solve your issue, I'd really appreciate the upvote, then I can continue to help others. Thank you.